# Windows 8: want to force a specific website be opened only by one of two internet lines avialable

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, firewall, rules

I have a PC with win 8 with two different available wifi internet lines available.

I want to to force a specific website be opened only by only one of internet connection and other websites be opened by the other internet connection.

At the same time only one of them is preferred by windows and connected.

Is there any way to do this?

Is there any windows firewall software having the ability to add such rule to it?

```
    IPv4 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.3     25
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
          192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.3    281
          192.168.1.3  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.3    281
        192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.3    281
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.3    281
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.3    281
    ===========================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to modify route metrics for the specific connection. Windows selects route based on that. Please provide your current route table, by executing `route print` in command line, so I can improve my answer.

But first you need to add route by:

```
route ADD     157.0.0.0     MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.3
ROUTE command [destination] [MASK netmask]       [gateway]
```

I'm afraid that you cannot specify route by URL. It has to be IP address (157.0.0.0).

Comment: @Sandogh You have said that you have "two different available WiFi Internet connections", but as I can see on route table, there is only one external interface: 192.168.1.3 (127.0.0.1 is loopback interface). I think that Windows adapts route to latest connection. Could you reconnect the second interface and give me the logs again?

Comment: BTW What is the "specific website" IP address?

Comment: See if you can apply: [Microsoft Research Virtual WiFi](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/994abd5f-53d1-4dba-a9d8-8ba1dcccead7/)

Comment: it is made for XP. does it it work in win 8?

Comment: there is no specific ip address. there is a website with different servers with different ip addresses. are you sure there is no way for adding route based on website address?

Answer (score 0):

With only one internet connection active, I think this is impossible without some really complicated software.
Though, you could use static routes make window route any traffic to a specific IP address (like, the IP address of the "specific website) through one interface.
using cmd:

```
route ADD {ip address of specific website} MASK {network mask} {gateway ip}
```

That, of course, only works if those two wifi connections do not operate on the same network address and are both active.

Comment: thanks. is not it possible to use website domain name instead of website ip? because a website can have different servers with many different ip's